# what is a resource in UMA (OAuth2)?

Tags: access-control, oauth2

I'm currently having a look at OAuth and UMA and I often read about resource and resource server.
But I'm still unsure what exactly a resource can or can't represent.
Most of the time in the examples, API Endpoints or assets like images etc. are resources. "Things" that are exposed to the public and can be directly requested.

But in OAuth2/UMA is a resource a technical term or is it just conceptual?
Example:
my API provides a GET Method /User/GetUser/1

So is my API Endpoint or the actual user the resource?

if it is the API endpoint, is protecting the user "inside" my API out of OAuth2/UMA's scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both OAuth and UMA, a protected resource is conceptual, though ultimately based on the notion of the "web resource" primitive in web architecture. The user (resource owner) is not the resource. The digital data or other "stuff" the resource owner wants to control access to is the resource.

Many OAuth deployers talk about everything at a resource server as "the protected resource" (PR), so a whole API tends to be thought of as one resource. UMA was specifically designed to enable multiple protected resources (and for each of those to be able to have different scopes as warranted), to allow for use cases such as files and folders vs. just API endpoints. So things are more flexible (and therefore complex) in UMA, out of the box.

The UMA Implementer's Guide has a section called [Considerations Regarding Resource Server Permission Requests](https://kantarainitiative.org/confluence/display/uma/UMA+Implementer%27s+Guide#UMAImplementer%27sGuide-perm-request-patternsConsiderationsRegardingResourceServerPermissionRequests) with some examples of scopes that, in passing, may suggest additional types of protected resources to you.

[This section](https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/wg/rec-oauth-uma-federated-authz-2.0.html#fed-authz) in the UMA FedAuthz spec discusses how it's the resource server's job to design protected-resource boundaries: "The resource server defines the boundaries of resources and the scopes available to each resource, and interprets how clients' resource requests map to permission requests, by virtue of being the publisher of the API being protected and using the protection API to communicate to the authorization server."

An example I deal with frequently is a consumer (or clinical) IoT device. The question that arises is: Should the whole device (basically its entire API) be one resource? Or, how should resources within it be broken down? For example, each set of "live"/streaming data coming off the device might be one resource the user will want to control. Sets of historical data already stored in the cloud might be other resources. Device functions (pan camera, turn device off/on, whatever) might be another single resource, controllable through scopes.

Some of the boundary design considerations here have to do with usability. (Perhaps similar to the process of choosing Google Apps Share button dropdown items!...)

Some background about definitions: OAuth (IETF RFC 6749) [informally defines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1) a protected resource as an access-restricted resource. UMA2 adopts OAuth terminology along with a few enhancements; its Federated Authorization spec also [formally defines](https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/wg/rec-oauth-uma-federated-authz-2.0.html#resource-registration-endpoint) how to effect resource protection: "Protection of a resource at the authorization server begins on successful [resource] registration and ends on successful deregistration."

I hope this helps!